# check whether a string contains two or more words from my list (python)

Tags: python, string, substring

I'm trying to extract relevant information from my text.

I'm now using python.

Since, if any (s in mytext for s in mylist):

searches too many irrelevant strings,

I'm trying to find strings which contain two or more words from mylist.

So, my question is "How can i only choose sentences which contain two or more words from my list"

Thank you for your help!

Have a good day!

Comment: at least try witing the code once and then ask help here for errors instead of blindly asking us how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Split the string.

2) Check occurrence of keyword in text.

3) If count greater than or equal to 2 print the text

```
keywords = ['the', 'apple' , 'fruit']
text = ['apple is a fruit', 'orange is fruit', 'the apple', 'the orange', 'the orange fruit']

for element in text:
    if len(set(keywords)&set(element.split())) >=2 :
        print element
```

Output:

```
apple is a fruit
the apple
the orange fruit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If this answer helps you , please accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't get the exactly what you want but What I understand is :

```
list = ["This is tesing", "hello","My name", "This is not test"]
for sentense in list :
   if len(sentense.split()) >= 2:
      print sentense
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
This is tesing
My name
This is not test
```

I hope this will help you...

Comment: This searches for sentences of length at least 2, but the OP seems to want to find sentences which contain at least 2 words from a specific list of words.